# Add two R data frames of different sizes

Tags: r

If two data frames are

```
  symbol wgt
1     A   2
2     C   4
3     D   6

  symbol wgt
1     A  20
2     D  10
```

how can I add them so that missing observations for a "symbol" in either data frame are treated as zero, giving

```
  symbol wgt
1     A   22
2     C   4
3     D   16
```

Comment: Perhaps you could exhance your example data by adding a row with E=16 to the second `data.frame` to support the case *so that missing observations for a "symbol" in either data frame are treated as zero*

Comment: What is the expected handling of `NA` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table` and the data provided in the answer of @RonakShah and @Duck the solution could be a simple aggregation:

```
# Convert data.frame to data.table (very fast since inplace)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# combine both data.frames into one data.frame, group by symbol, apply the sum (NAs are ignored = counted as zero)
rbind(df1,df2)[, sum(wgt, na.rm = TRUE), by = symbol]

# Output
   symbol V1
1:      A 22
2:      C  4
3:      D 16
```

Note: If you want to use base R only (without `data.table`) you could use `aggregate` instead:

```
aggregate(wgt ~ symbol, rbind(df1,df2), sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join the two dataframes by `symbol` , replace `NA` with 0 and add the two weights.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'symbol') %>%
   mutate(wgt.y  = replace(wgt.y, is.na(wgt.y), 0), 
          wgt  = wgt.x + wgt.y) %>%
  select(-wgt.x, -wgt.y)

#  symbol wgt
#1      A  22
#2      C   4
#3      D  16
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(symbol = c("A", "C", "D"), wgt = c(2L, 4L, 6L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(symbol = c("A", "D"), wgt = c(20L, 10L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: `sum` with `na.rm = TRUE` might be a shorter way

Comment: Yes, but then I have to add `rowwise` which will make it slower.

Comment: I am not quite sure if a left join will work if only the right side of the join contains a symbol + wgt... (*"so that missing observations for a "symbol" in either data frame are treated as zero"*)

Comment: You could use `full_join` however.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one line solution by pipes:

```
#Data
library(dplyr)
df1 <- structure(list(symbol = c("A", "C", "D"), wgt = c(2L, 4L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
df2 <- structure(list(symbol = c("A", "D"), wgt = c(20L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2"))

#Code
df1 %>% left_join(df2,by = 'symbol') %>% mutate(wgt = rowSums(.[-1],na.rm=T)) %>% select(c(1,4))

  symbol wgt
1      A  22
2      C   4
3      D  16
```